# Adding code examples in scaladoc

Tags: scala, scaladoc

What is the standard convention (or tag) to add code examples in ScalaDoc? Example in the code below, I want to provide coding example to demonstrate it's usage:

```
/**
 * Adds a filter on DB Table Query if value is defined. Example:
 *
 * {code}
 * val startIncluded: Option[Timestamp] = _
 * tableQuery.filter(startIncluded)(startTime => _.start >= startTime)
 * {code}
 *
 * ... other doc ...
 */
def filter (value: Option[T])(condition: T => Table => Option[Boolean]) = {
```

Like in javadocs, [@code](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/javadoc_tip_code_and_literal) is used.

Comment: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Syntax

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `{{{ }}}` [to delimit code blocks](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Syntax):

```
/**
 * This is a comment.
 * 
 * {{{
 * this.is(example.code)
 * }}}
 */
 def is(some: Code): Unit
```